# CSS Menu item render at bottom and than go to right

Tags: jquery, html, css, sidebar

I had created a menu using css and jquery.When i click on icon it display items render at bottom and than item goes to right.

But i want to change this behaviour. I want to change it in the way that menu items displays at right side with transition.

HTML CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Collapsible sidebar using Bootstrap 3</title>
         <!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!-- Our Custom CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <!-- Sidebar Holder -->
            <nav id="sidebar" class="active">
                <div class="sidebar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="sidebarCollapse btn btn-primary navbar-btn">
                        <div></div>
                        <div></div>
                        <div></div>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <ul class="list-unstyled components">
                    <li>
                        <a data-target="#Stammdaten" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                            <div>
                                <i class="stammdaten-icon"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="collapse" id="Stammdaten">
                                <h4>Stammdaten</h4>
                                <p>Kunden</p>
                                <p>Lieferanten</p>
                                <p>Artikel</p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a data-target="#Auf" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                            <div>
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="collapse" id="Auf">
                                <h4>Aufträge</h4>
                                <p>Artikel suchen</p>
                                <p>Lieferanten suchen</p>
                                <p>Mappe öffnen</p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a data-target="#Statistik" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                            <div>
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="collapse" id="Statistik">
                                <h4>Statistik</h4>
                                <p>Statistik anlegen</p>
                                <p>Auswertung</p>
                                <p>Zeitraum festlegen</p>
                                <p>Auswertung</p>
                                <p>Mappe öffnen</p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a data-target="#Einstellungen" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                            <div>
                                <i class="einstellungen-icon"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="collapse" id="Einstellungen">
                                <h4>Einstellungen</h4>
                                <p>Artikel suchen</p>
                                <p>Lieferanten suchen</p>
                                <p>Mappe öffnen</p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <div class="sidebar-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="sidebarCollapse btn btn-primary navbar-btn">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left"></i>
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </nav>

            <!-- Page Content Holder -->
            <div id="content">

            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- jQuery CDN -->
         <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
         <!-- Bootstrap Js CDN -->
         <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
                    if ($('#sidebar').hasClass('active')) {
                        $('.collapse').collapse('show');
                        $('li').addClass('active');
                    } else {
                        $('li').removeClass('active');
                        $('.collapse.in').collapse('hide');
                    }
                    $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
                });
                $('[data-toggle="collapse"]').click(function() {
                    if ($('#sidebar').hasClass('active')) {
                        $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
                    }
                    if ($('li').hasClass('active')) {
                        $('li').removeClass('active');
                    }
                    $('.collapse.in').collapse('hide');
                });
            });
         </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS CODE

```
 @import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,600,700";


    body {
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        background: #fafafa;
    }

    p {
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        font-size: 1.1em;
        font-weight: 300;
        line-height: 1.7em;
        color: #999;
    }

    a, a:hover, a:focus {
        color: inherit;
        text-decoration: none;
        transition: all 0.3s;
    }

    .navbar {
        padding: 15px 10px;
        background: #fff;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 0;
        margin-bottom: 40px;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }

    .navbar-btn {
        box-shadow: none;
        outline: none !important;
        border: none;
        background-color: #007AAC;
        margin: 0;
        height: 80px;
        width: 80px;
        border-radius: 0;
    }

    .navbar-btn div {
        width: 26px;
        height: 4px;
        background-color: white;
        margin: 6px auto;
    }

    .line {
        width: 100%;
        height: 1px;
        border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
        margin: 40px 0;
    }

    i, span {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    /* ---------------------------------------------------
        SIDEBAR STYLE
    ----------------------------------------------------- */
    .wrapper {
        display: flex;
        align-items: stretch;
    }

    #sidebar {
        min-width: 290px;
        max-width: 290px;
        background: #144667;
        color: #fff;
        transition: all 0.3s;
        padding-bottom: 80px;
        position: relative;
    }

    #sidebar .sidebar-footer {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: #007AAC;
        text-align: right;
    }

    #sidebar .sidebar-footer button {
        font-size: 30px;
    }

    #sidebar .sidebar-footer button .glyphicon {
        top: unset;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    #sidebar .sidebar-footer button .glyphicon-menu-right {
        display: none;
    }

    #sidebar.active .sidebar-footer button .glyphicon-menu-right {
        display: block;
    }

    #sidebar.active .sidebar-footer button .glyphicon-menu-left {
        display: none;
    }

    #sidebar.active {
        min-width: 80px;
        max-width: 80px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #sidebar ul li a {
        text-align: left;
    }

    #sidebar.active ul li a {
        padding: 20px 10px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 0.85em;
    }

    #sidebar.active ul li a div {
        padding-left: 6px;
    }
    #sidebar.active ul li a div:nth-child(2) {
        display: none;
    }

    #sidebar.active ul li a i {
        margin-right:  0;
        display: block;
        font-size: 1.8em;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

    #sidebar.active ul li a i.glyphicon {
        font-size: 2.6em;
        text-align: left;
        margin-top: 5px;
    }

    #sidebar.active a[aria-expanded="false"]::before, #sidebar.active a[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
        top: auto;
        bottom: 5px;
        right: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(50%);
        transform: translateX(50%);
    }

    #sidebar .sidebar-header {
        background: #144667;
    }

    #sidebar .sidebar-header strong {
        display: none;
        font-size: 1.8em;
    }

    #sidebar ul li a {
        padding: 30px 12px;
        font-size: 1.1em;
        display: block;
    }

    #sidebar ul li a div {
        vertical-align: middle;
        padding-left: 28px;
    }

    #sidebar ul li a div:first-child {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    #sidebar.active ul li a div.collapse.in {
        display: none;
    }

    #sidebar ul li a div.collapse.in {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    #sidebar ul li a:hover {
        color: #7386D5;
        background: #fff;
    }
    #sidebar ul li a i {
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        font-size: 2.2em;
    }

    #sidebar ul li.active > a, a[aria-expanded="true"] {
        color: #fff;
    }

    #sidebar ul li > a[aria-expanded="true"] {
        border-left: 6px solid #E5911A;
        background: #113B58;
    }
    #sidebar ul li.active > a[aria-expanded="true"] {
        border-left: 0;
    }

    #sidebar ul li a:hover {
        background: #113B58;
        color: white;
    }

    .stammdaten-icon {
        background: url(./icons/Stammdaten.png) no-repeat;
    }

    .einstellungen-icon {
        background: url(./icons/Einstellungen.png) no-repeat;
    }

    ul ul a {
        font-size: 0.9em !important;
        padding-left: 30px !important;
        background: #6d7fcc;
    }


    /* ---------------------------------------------------
        CONTENT STYLE
    ----------------------------------------------------- */
    #content {
        padding: 20px;
        min-height: 100vh;
        transition: all 3s;
    }


    /* ---------------------------------------------------
        MEDIAQUERIES
    ----------------------------------------------------- */
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
        #sidebar.active {
            margin-left: 0 !important;
        }

        #sidebar .sidebar-header h3 {
            display: none;
        }

        #sidebar ul li a {
            padding: 20px 10px;
        }

        #sidebar ul li a span {
            font-size: 0.85em;
        }
        #sidebar ul li a i {
            margin-right:  0;
            display: block;
        }

        #sidebar ul li a i {
            font-size: 1.3em;
        }
        #sidebar {
            margin-left: 0;
        }

    }
```

Here is a working Pen

https://codepen.io/naitik_kundalia/pen/vbgxJN

Comment: You won't need bottom position right? can you please explain clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change CSS

```
#sidebar ul li a {
  padding: 30px 12px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vbgpQK